# In orientdb how to select any 5 rows from set of data

Tags: orientdb

My database class is having 1000 rows out of which i want when i fire query it should give me any arbitrary 5 rows on each hit, can or can not be unique.

What i need to add in query for same?

Comment: What query are you trying to use now? What is your OrientDB version?

Comment: Query: select  from className where columnName="XYZ".....OrientDB version : 2.2.3

Comment: Have you tried my answer, does it fits your needs?

Comment: yes i tried your approach...it helped...thanks

Comment: You can mark it as correct clicking on the grey tick in the left. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple JavaScript function which will take all records from v and return 5 random:

```
var g=orient.getDatabase(); 
var b=g.query("select from v");
var result = [];
for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
   item=b[Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length)]
   result.push(item);
}
return result;
```

Than you can query for results using:

```
select expand(result) from (select randomFunc() as result)
```

See screenshots from Studio:

[image]
[image]

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently there isn't a random function.
You could see this [link](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/1946).

Hope it helps.